# Crash when editing records

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I have to made a project of C++ in Visual Basic 6.0 with GUI. The project is a examination database for students. The functionality of this program is that its add records and show records and print the clearance slip for student exams.

I made some of its part but i can not able to add records in a file db.dat I made some menus and and dialog boxes for add deleting and viewing records but only the add dialog box open and it also not working properly and don't store the data in the file while deleting or modifying the record program is going to be crashed. i don't understand what to do plz help me out. The code of the program is below:

```
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "resource.h"

struct student
{
    char name[25];
    char address[40];
    char college[10];
    unsigned long int phone_no;
    unsigned int batch_no;
    char course[2];
    char start_date[10];
    char class_timings[15];
    char computer_timings[15];
    float total_fees;
    float first_inst;
    float second_inst;
    float balance;
};

CFile fp("student.dat",CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeNoTruncate|CFile::modeReadWrite);

CString g_name;
unsigned int g_batchno;

class about_dialog: public CDialog
{
public:
    about_dialog():CDialog (IDD_DIALOG1)
    {}
};

class add_dialog: public CDialog
{
private:
    struct student e;
    CString s[7];

    public:

        add_dialog():CDialog(IDD_DIALOG2)
        {
            e.phone_no=e.batch_no=0;
            e.total_fees=e.first_inst=0.0;
            e.second_inst=e.balance=0.0;
        }

        void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *p)
        {
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT1,s[0]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT2,s[1]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT4,s[2]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT5,e.phone_no);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT6,e.batch_no);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO5,s[3]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT7,s[4]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO6,s[5]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO7,s[6]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT3,e.total_fees);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT8,e.first_inst);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT9,e.second_inst);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT10,e.balance);
        }

        void save()
        {
            CDialog::OnOK();

            strcpy(e.name,s[0]);
            strcpy(e.college,s[1]);
            strcpy(e.address,s[2]);
            strcpy(e.course,s[3]);
            strcpy(e.start_date,s[4]);
            strcpy(e.class_timings,s[5]);
            strcpy(e.computer_timings,s[6]);

            fp.SeekToEnd();
            fp.Write(&e,sizeof(e));
        }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(add_dialog,CDialog)
ON_COMMAND(601,save)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class getname_dialog: public CDialog
{
public:
    getname_dialog(): CDialog(IDD_DIALOG3)
    {
        g_name="";
        g_batchno=0;
    }

    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *p)
    {
        DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT1,g_batchno);
        DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT2,g_name);
    }
};

class modify_dialog: public CDialog
{
private:

    CString s[7];
    struct student e;

    public:

        modify_dialog(struct student ee):CDialog (IDD_DIALOG2)
        {
            e=ee;
            s[0]=ee.name;
            s[1]=ee.college;
            s[2]=ee.address;
            s[3]=ee.course;
            s[4]=ee.start_date;
            s[5]=ee.class_timings;
            s[6]=ee.computer_timings;
        }

        void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange *p)
        {
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT1,s[0]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT2,s[1]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT4,s[2]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT5,e.phone_no);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT6,e.batch_no);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO5,s[3]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT7,s[4]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO6,s[5]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_COMBO7,s[6]);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT3,e.total_fees);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT8,e.first_inst);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT9,e.second_inst);
            DDX_Text(p,IDC_EDIT10,e.balance);
        }

        void save()
        {
            CDialog::OnOK();

            strcpy(e.name,s[0]);
            strcpy(e.college,s[1]);
            strcpy(e.address,s[2]);
            strcpy(e.course,s[3]);
            strcpy(e.start_date,s[4]);
            strcpy(e.class_timings,s[5]);
            strcpy(e.computer_timings,s[6]);

            fp.Seek(-(long)sizeof(e),CFile::current);
            fp.Write(&e,sizeof(e));
        }

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(modify_dialog,CDialog)
ON_COMMAND(601,save)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class myframe: public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    myframe()
    {
        CString mywindowclass;

        CBrush mybrush;
        mybrush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(225,255,255));

        mywindowclass=AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW,AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW),mybrush,AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1));

        Create(mywindowclass,"DATABASE",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,rectDefault,0,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));

    }

    void about()
    {
        about_dialog diag;
        diag.DoModal();
    }

    void addrec()
    {
        Invalidate();
        add_dialog diag;
        diag.DoModal();

    }

    void byname()
    {
        struct student e;

        CClientDC d(this);
        CRect r;
        int y;

        char str[80];
        fp.SeekToBegin();
        y=0;

        GetClientRect(&r);

        CBrush mybrush (RGB(255,255,255));

        d.FillRect(&r,&mybrush);

        while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>=sizeof(e))
        {
            sprintf(str,"%-25s %-40s",e.name,e.address);

            d.TextOut(0,y,str,strlen(str));

            y+=15;
        }
    }

    void college()
    {
        struct student e;

        CClientDC d(this);

        int y;
        char str[90];
        CRect r;

        GetClientRect(&r);
        CBrush mybrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        d.FillRect(&r,&mybrush);

        fp.SeekToBegin();
        y=0;

        while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>=sizeof(e))
        {
            sprintf(str,"%-25s %-20s %-6u %-10s",e.name, e.course,e.batch_no,e.college);
            d.TextOut(0,y,str,strlen(str));
            y+=15;
        }

    }

    void batch()
    {
        struct student e;

        CClientDC d(this);

        int y;
        char str[90];
        CRect r;

        GetClientRect(&r);
        CBrush mybrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        d.FillRect(&r,&mybrush);

        fp.SeekToBegin();
        y=0;

        while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>=sizeof(e))
        {
            sprintf(str,"%-25s %-20s %-15s %-15s",e.name,e.course,e.class_timings,e.computer_timings);
            d.TextOut(0,y,str,strlen(str));
            y+=15;
        }
    }

    void defaulters()
    {
        struct student e;

        CClientDC d(this);

        int y;
        char str[90];
        CRect r;

        GetClientRect(&r);
        CBrush mybrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        d.FillRect(&r,&mybrush);

        fp.SeekToBegin();
        y=0;

        while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>=sizeof(e))
        {
            if(e.balance>0)
            {
                sprintf(str,"%-25s %-20s %-6.6f %-6.6f %-6.6f",e.name,e.course,e.first_inst,e.second_inst,e.balance);
                d.TextOut(0,y,str,strlen(str));
                y+=15;      
            }
        }
    }

    void modifyrec()
    {
        Invalidate();

        bool found;
        struct student e;

        getname_dialog diag;

        if(diag.DoModal()==IDOK)
        {
            found=false;
            fp.SeekToBegin();

            while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>=sizeof(e))
            {
                if(e.batch_no==g_batchno && strcmp(e.name,g_name)==0)
                {
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(found==true)
            {
                modify_dialog mdiag(e);
                mdiag.DoModal();
            }
            else
                MessageBox("Record Not Found","Modify Record");
        }
    }

    void delrec()
    {
        bool found;
        struct student e;

        Invalidate();
        getname_dialog diag;
        if(diag.DoModal()==IDOK)
        {
            found=false;
            fp.SeekToBegin();

            CFile ft("temp.dat",CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);

            while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>=sizeof(e))
            {
                if(e.batch_no==g_batchno && strcmp(e.name,g_name)==0)

                    found=true;
                else
                    ft.Write(&e,sizeof(e));
            }
            if(found==false)
                MessageBox("Record Not Found","Delete Record");
            fp.Close();
            ft.Close();

            CFile::Remove("students.dat");
            CFile::Rename("temp.dat","students.dat");
            fp.Open("student.dat",CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeNoTruncate|CFile::modeReadWrite);
        }
    }
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(myframe,CFrameWnd)

ON_COMMAND(101,about)
ON_COMMAND(201,addrec)
ON_COMMAND(301,byname)
ON_COMMAND(302,college)
ON_COMMAND(303,batch)
ON_COMMAND(304,defaulters)
ON_COMMAND(401,modifyrec)
ON_COMMAND(501,delrec)

END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class myapp: public CWinApp
{
    public:

        int InitInstance()
        {
            myframe *fr;
            fr=new myframe;
            fr->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            m_pMainWnd=fr;

            return 1;
        }
};

myapp app;
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. How about restricting the code to the relevant part? What is the error you get?

Comment: You should really show a testcase of the exact problem you're having instead of posting all your code.

Comment: And tell us what exactly does the program say when you encounter the crash.

Comment: It would be more efficient if you had narrowed down the problem and made your problem more specific, samii.

Comment: Debugg Assertion Failed...... This is the error i got when i try to modify or delete a record or also it dosen't show any existing records or neither add any in to the file

Answer (score 0):

```
  Object P;
            int pos=sizeof(Object)*PID-sizeof(Object);
            f.open("File.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::ate);
            f.seekp(0,ios::beg);
            f.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
            f.read((char*)&P,sizeof(Object));
            f.close();
            return 0;
```

in this approach im writing Objects to the file... its easy to search and retrieve data ..try this approach  ..also don't write `strings` to files it gives IO errors ... use character arrays to

Comment: did you please edit the above code for showing where you want to add the code or how to use the character arrays

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure add_dialog::save() gets called, given the ON_COMMAND(601,save) declaration?

Please check that the I/O operations on fp succeeded by checking the return status. Example: if open of the file failed, attempts to write to it will fail miserably. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d65ch27(v=VS.80).aspx

And since you tagged this homework: I would suggest wrapping the CFile inside a new class (`CStudentDB` ?). You can put all the I/O details inside this class, write and debug it only once and offer an easier interface (example: `while (studentDB.Read(e)) {..}`) to the GUI part of your program.